# Keeping line breaks when reading a file

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I want to read a file and modify it but whenever the new file is created everything stays on one line. Therefore, my question is how can I keep line breaks without removing them?

```
public class JavaProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "";
        StringBuilder convert = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        File file = new File ("PATH");

            try {
                Scanner input = new Scanner (file);
                while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                        text = input.nextLine();

                        char [] arr = text.toCharArray();
                        char [] newArr = encrypt(3, arr);

                        for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
                            convert.append(newArr[i]);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                try {
                    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter (document);

                    printer.append(convert);
                    printer.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: How do you expect the file to be decrypted?  If you want to encrypt the line terminator too, then add it back before encryption.  Otherwise, add it back afterwards.  If you don't specify this and a third party tries to decrypt the file, the file may not be decrypted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line break at the moment you write each line.
In your case is after the for loop that appends the encrypted characters:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
       convert.append(newArr[i]);
convert.append("\r\n");
```

Adding a new line in Java is as simple as including “\n” or “\r” or “\r\n” at the end of our string depending on the SO you are using. But nowadays the file editors recognise all of them so it might not be a problem whether you chose one or another.

And regarding to why they are 'lost' if you look at the docs of the `nextLine()` method it says:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, **excluding any line separator at the end**. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

So you have to add the line separators back if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading input one line at a time, which means implicitly that you have a line break every time your read stops.

So each time you write a saved buffer, write out a newline.

```
try {
Scanner input = new Scanner (file);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    text = input.nextLine();

    char [] arr = text.toCharArray();
    char [] newArr = encrypt(3, arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        convert.append(newArr[i]);
        convert.append(System.lineSeparator());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a End Of Line **\r\n**:

```
convert.append("\r\n");
```

Or a **Line Separator**:

```
convert.append(System.lineSeparator());
```

So, this is an edit of your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "";
    StringBuilder convert = new StringBuilder();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

    File file = new File ("C:\\document.txt");

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            text = input.nextLine();

            char [] arr = text.toCharArray();
            char [] newArr = arr;

            for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
                convert.append(newArr[i]);
            }

           // use this:
            convert.append(System.lineSeparator());
           // Or this:
            convert.append("\r\n");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    try {
        // write file
        PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter("C:\\My New File.txt");

        printer.append(convert);
        printer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```